# Publishing data from Spacenav node to other topics

Tags: ros, teleop, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I'm working on a small teleoperation program (currently only for the turtlesim and afterwards for an UR5e robot arm) using a Spacenav 3dconnexion joystick and I'm trying to figure out how to send the Twist data from the Spacenav node which publishes to
any other topic (in short, how to make the spacenav node publish to other topics).

Is there a built-in feature which I can use to change the name of the topic where it publishes the twist messages?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387081/publishing-data-from-spacenav-node-to-other-topics/) by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That would be *remapping*.

See [roslaunch/XML/remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) for `.launch` files and [Remapping Arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) for nodes and a more general description.

Finally, refer to #q303611 for additional discussion.

---

Edit: and whatever you do: do *not* edit source code to change topic names. That is almost always unneeded and very much an anti-pattern.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on 2021-09-23**:
Thanks! This solution works perfectly! Although I have an unexpected problem: when connecting to a robot arm, the twist values which the spacenav joystick sends to the robot are too big for safe teleoperation (some values even exceed 0.3) and so the robot moves too quickly and the safety feature of the robot stops it. How do I manage to reduce the values sent and keep them between some desired intervals, for example: -0.06 to 0.06?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-23**:
That seems like a different question, which you should post as a new one.

---

Edit: seems you did: #q387180.